# RoR: Cannot Migrate Database to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having trouble migrating my database to Heroku. I have checked the other issues that address this to no avail. I can really use a second pair of eyes on my code to help me figure this out.

This is the error I get:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "props" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_1d3f70cf04"
FOREIGN KEY ("prop_id")
  REFERENCES "props" ("id")
```

[image]

It seems to get caught while migrating this file:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :prop, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This is the migration file where I create the table props:

```
class CreateProps < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :props do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My schema is here:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160528205746) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "choice"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "created_by"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "prop_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "commenter"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "prop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["prop_id"], name: "index_comments_on_prop_id", using: :btree

  create_table "props", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "choice"
    t.string   "answer"
    t.integer  "answerId"
  end

  add_index "props", ["user_id"], name: "index_props_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "user_answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "answer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "score",           default: 0
    t.integer  "prop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "created_by"
    t.boolean  "admin",           default: false
    t.integer  "answers_id"
    t.integer  "answer_id"
  end

  add_index "users", ["answer_id"], name: "index_users_on_answer_id", using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["prop_id"], name: "index_users_on_prop_id", using: :btree

  create_table "wins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "correctAnswer"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  add_index "wins", ["user_id"], name: "index_wins_on_user_id", using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "users", "answers"
end
```

Comment: Apart from what bkunzi01 said, try to fix the problem by migration. Because, once you are doing db:drop, all the data will be lost. So if something like this happens again in production, you cannot afford to lose the data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are creating a reference to a table that is not yet created.  Remove the reference from that migration to props, then add the props table and then add a migration implementing the association.  If you dont need the data currently in the db I would do a "rake db:drop" and edit the migration files (only if you arent collaborating with others!)

Update:

Do rails g migration add_ref_to_comments

Then edit the migration to have:

def change
add_reference :props, :comment, index: true
end

Comment: Thank you! Can you please show/tell me what the new migration would look like to reimplement the association? I am not sure exactly how to recreate the association.

Comment: Thank you...I tried remove a few lines from the code including the association from my schema and from the migration file and it still did not work?

Comment: This is the line I delete from the migration file ```      t.references :prop, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

Comment: You need to drop the database first then edit the migration file like you did in the comment above then run "bundle exec rake db:create" then "bundle exec rake db:migrate". Just remember this will lose all your data you currently have as long as that is ok.

Comment: Run "bundle exec rake db:drop" to drop the database then run the create method in my comment above with the newly saved migration files and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Ok, that works. I removed      ```t.references :prop, index: true, foreign_key: true``` and then did as you said. Problem is: all of my migration files and relations are set up like this. What is the equivalent later migration I need to run to re-associate props with comments?

Comment: You can leave the props association in the "create props table" migration as it was since it will be called after the comments table was created.

Comment: ok so i got it to migrate but since I removed the line "t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true" from props I lost this column in my props table. How do I add it back with a later migration? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Go to the rails association guides and look at the relationship you want.  Its probably a has_many and belongs_to relationship.  Do posts have many comments?